# Setting Variables Value in a File in Different Directory Using Loops and sed Bash Script

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to write a bash script that will check five variable values in a file in a different directory and update them accordingly. 
Since there is five variables, I was thinking to do it in a for loop, but I don't know how to compare these values. 
What I'd like to have is pseudo code:

```
var_f=(server_name app_name metadata1 metadata2 metadata)  #the variable name in file
var_v=(server1 app /tmp/2 tmp/3 /tmp/config.xml
for i in "${var_f[@]}"
do
   if var_f(i)~=var_v(i)
            sed -i -e 's/server_name=RANDOM_VAL/server_name=server1/g'   server.properties
    else
         then do nothing   
    fi
 done
```

The code I've so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd '/home/me/'
set -- $(<server.properties)
echo $server_name # jsut to see if set command is working
sed -i -e 's@server_name=@server_name=server1@g' server.properties
sed -i -e 's@app_name=@app_name=app@g' server.properties
sed -i -e 's@metadata1=@metadata1=/tmp/2@g' server.properties
sed -i -e 's@meatadata2=@metadata2=/tmp/3@g server.properties
sed -i -e 's@metadata=@metadata=/config.xml@g' server.properties
cd '/home/my/test/'
```

How can I run through var_f and var_v and compare the two? 
the value of var_f from the file is obtainable using the --set command, but I don't know how to compare it to the correct values (var_v). Also, var_v are the correct values that will replace the wrong ones using the for loop and if statement.

Any help will be very appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Perhaps you could write out the 5 cases separately; then we could work from there to refactor into a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. For one case I need to check the value and update if needed. 
the commands for the first case is: 
    'cd '/home/me''
    'sed -i -e 's/a=RANDOM_VAL/a=server1/g' my.properties' 
    'cd '/home/test/''
rewrites the value to file, BUT:
It doesnt work if the new value is a=/temp/2/ for example. And I'd like to fix it, if possible.

Comment: Also, the second part of the question is how to I compare the variable value stored in file to the variable value in var_v?

Comment: @shellter Perfect! Thank you very much, it fixed the slashes issue.

Comment: @Amit: Glad that helped, but not clear about your comparison problem, especially the `for i` . Do you want to see if the value of $i is contained in any of the elements in `var_v`? Maybe more descriptive variable names will help for your array names? I think for the inner sed in the loop, you want `'s@i=.*@a='"${var_f[$i]}"@'`. Recall that in shell, the single-quote char prevents var expansion, while dbl-quotes allow var expansion AND that you "bump-up" single and dbl-qoted strings next to each other to create 1 string (as seen by the cmd, after shell has expanded vars). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I've changed the variable names in the array per your suggestion. The script as it is, going to rewrite the correct values in the fields everytime the script/sed command is called; clearly not that useful. 
The set command allow me to retrieve the value of the element from var_f array, and I would like to compare this value to the correct in var_v which are the correct values. 
So, if I have a for loop that runs five times (as the number of elements in the array) and compare each element value.

Comment: For example:


    'for i in var_f do
       if $var_f(i) not equal to var_v(i) do
            sed -i -e 's@servername=@servername=server1@g' config.properties
       else
            do nothing and exit
       done
     done`

Note that by $var_f(i) i mean the value of servername from the file, in the case i=1. I hope this is more coherent. Perhaps I should start with just understanding the for loop.

Comment: I seem to fail in formatting the code in the comments....

Comment: use back-quotes around the code samples in comments. Better yet, consider updating your question to include your best code so far. Recall that the `{}` tool at top of text input box will reformat select text in code format. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think it advisable to update all variables in a single sed run.

```
#!/bin/bash
var_f=(server_name app_name metadata1 metadata2 metadata) #variable name
var_v=(server1 app /tmp/2 /tmp/3 /tmp/config.xml)
for (( i=0; i < ${#var_f[*]}; ++i ))
do
    substitutions+="s@${var_f[$i]}=\S*@${var_f[$i]}=${var_v[$i]}@;"
done
sed -i "$substitutions" /home/me/server.properties
```

Are you seriously bothered by the file being rewritten every time the script runs? Presumably comparing the current values to the correct ones would take longer.