# Check Variable Value in File and Replace If Needed Bash Script

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, sed

This question is related to post: 
[Setting Variables Value in a File in Different Directory Using Loops and sed Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708135/setting-variables-value-in-a-file-in-different-directory-using-loops-and-sed-bas)

I'm looking for a way to check variable value in file and update it as needed. To change the value I do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd '/home/me/'
source server.properties
server_var="$server_name"
echo "$server_var"
echo "$application_name"
if [ "$server_var" != "server1" ]; then
    echo "Uncorrect Value"
    sed -i -e 's@server_name=$server_var@server_name=server1@g' server.properties
fi
cd '/home/test/'
```

Thank you for the suggestion, now my if statement work, but the `sed` command doesnt update the variable value in the file. Can you please point me in the right direction regarding this issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ -n "$server_name" ]
then
    sed ...
fi
```

BTW, I don't think your `set` command can set `$server_name`. It will set `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I followed the discussion here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652753/loading-variables-from-a-text-file-into-bash-script   regarding the set -- $(<server.properties) but it doesn't seem to work. 
Do you mind explaining what's the condition in [ -n "$server_name"]?

Comment: source server.properties seems to do the job.

Comment: Actually, I was missing "" instead of ''

Comment: If you look in that other question, you'll see that the answer uses `$1` and `$2`, just as I said. RTFM.